# How to save cookies locally using a C# app?

Tags: c#, cookies

I have c# code which makes a request to a particular domain and gets the response cookies.

Now when i go to the same URL in Internet Explorer i am prompted for credentials, because the cookies that my app got doesn't seem to save in the 'Temporary Internet Files' folder like how regular cookies are stored.

So how do i store cookies for future use via IE even if my local c# app is closed?

I do get valid cookies in my response.cookies.

**[Added More Information]**

Internet Explorer 8
Visual Studio 2010
Windows 7 64Bit

Here is my call for InternetSetCookieEx

What i am doing is going to URL1 with Cookie1 in the request, i get more cookies in my response which are needed to authenticate URL2, URL2 recieves the cookies and sends more cookies. Now a separate call to URL2 is sent from a webbrowser control which when seen on Fiddler doesnt seem to carry the cookies which i have from response2.

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
 public static extern bool InternetSetCookieEx(string UrlName, string CookieName, string CookieData);

                URL1 = "my.domain.com/page1.aspx";
                URL2 = "my.domain.com/page2.aspx";

                // Request to URL1 
                HttpWebRequest request1 = HttpWebRequest.Create(URL1) as HttpWebRequest;

                request1.Method = "GET";
                request1.Accept = "*/*";
                request1.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
                request1.UserAgent = "CookieCreator";
                request1.KeepAlive = true;
                request1.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

                Uri uri1 = new Uri(URL1);
                request1.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                request1.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie() { Name = "Cookie1", Value = "Some Value", Domain = uri1.Host });
                HttpWebResponse response1 = (HttpWebResponse)request1.GetResponse();

                //Request to URL2
                HttpWebRequest request2 = HttpWebRequest.Create(URL2) as HttpWebRequest;
                request2.Method = "GET";
                request2.Accept = "application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*";
                request2.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
                request2.UserAgent = "CookieCreator";
                request2.KeepAlive = true;
                request2.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

                Uri uri = new Uri(URL2);
                request2.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                //This sets session cookies, also adds the response cookie from URl1 into the request for URL2
                foreach (Cookie cookie1 in response1.Cookies)
                {
                    bool Output = InternetSetCookieEx(URL1, cookie1.Name, cookie1.Value);
                    request2.CookieContainer.Add(cookie1);
                }

                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                //This sets session cookies, hence will/should not be prompted for login credentials
                foreach (Cookie cookie2 in response2.Cookies)
                {
                    bool Output = InternetSetCookieEx(URL2, cookie.Name, cookie.Value);
                }
```

I get an exception when i use

```
bool Output = InternetSetCookieEx(URL1, cookie.Name, cookie.Value, "INTERNET_COOKIE_THIRD_PARTY");
```

*Exception*

> System.AccessViolationException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2147467261   Message=Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
>   Source=Thomson.Reuters.AFO.Components.Excel   StackTrace:
>          at Thomson.Reuters.AFO.Components.Excel.DFOCookieValidator.DFOCookieValidator.InternetSetCookieEx(String
>   UrlName, String CookieName, String CookieData, String flag)
>          at Thomson.Reuters.AFO.Components.Excel.DFOCookieValidator.DFOCookieValidator.ChartingCookieValidation(String
>   URL) in
>   C:\Codebase\DFO\AFO\Thomson.Reuters.AFO.Components.Excel\DFOCookieValidator\DFOCookieValidator.cs:line
>   180
>          at Thomson.Reuters.AFO.Components.Excel.AFOBrowser.AFOBrowserNewWindow.webBrowserNewWindow_Navigating(Object
>   sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e) in
>   C:\Codebase\DFO\AFO\Thomson.Reuters.AFO.Components.Excel\AFOBrowser\AFOBrowserNewWindow.xaml.cs:line
>   139
>          at System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser.OnNavigating(NavigatingCancelEventArgs
>   e)
>          at MS.Internal.Controls.WebBrowserEvent.BeforeNavigate2(Object pDisp, Object& url, Object& flags, Object& targetFrameName, Object&
>   postData, Object& headers, Boolean& cancel)   InnerException:

Comment: you dont say how your app talks to the website - embedded web browser control, http client, raw tcp,....

Comment: If allowed, that would be a BIG security problem. Any app could inject cookies to your browser

Comment: of course its allowed, its just files.

Comment: @pollirrata0: No. Any app running under the same user account as the browser is already able to do whatever it wants.  If an attacker is running code on your local machine, you've already lost.

Comment: I join pollirrata, it's not feasible and should not be. Look for popular application like facebook, twitter, ... they all ask for credentials when opening the app or browser page for the first time.

Comment: @cyrbil: No.  It is fundamentally impossible for a browser to prevent an application running under the same user from reading or writing its cookie store (or even saved passwords)

Comment: @Slaks: True, but I won't tell anyone to do so. OP should not search furthermore on this subject. I will write a more detailled answer with pro/con and how to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently its a session cookie that i was generating which will not store in IE cookie store. Hence any new HTTP request to the same domain/URL will not have any cookies in it.

So what i did was created a new webbrowsercontrol, with visibility as hidden and then navigated to that URL. The session cookies which i now have got stored in IE cookie store.

Answer (score 3):

Any applications can write cookie for a browser but it introduce problems that should be considered.

- First of all is compatibility, not anyone use the same browser and the same system. Transmitting a cookie from an app to user's browsers would be an hell to maintain.
- Next, any update of the browser way of handling cookie would broke your code, and you might end up with a broken browser too.
  Even if you just want to create a cookie for IE, users have differents versions.
- File locks, if the browser is using the *cookie file* you might not get the right to write on it
- User overwrite, if a user is already logged via the browser, creating the cookie for another user will simply disconnect the initial user.

But to answer the **how**, IE offers [WinINet APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385483%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and you can use [InternetSetCookie](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385107(v=vs.85).aspx) or [InternetSetCookieEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385108(v=vs.85).aspx)

For IE using theses methods would be the cleaniest way.

> On Windows Vista and above, Internet Explorer runs Internet content in Protected Mode, a sandbox with an isolated cookie store. In order to set a cookie in the Protected Mode sandbox from an external application running at Medium integrity (aka outside of Internet Explorer), you must use the [IESetProtectedModeCookie](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197007(VS.85).aspx) function.
>
> E10+ on Windows 8+ introduced Enhanced Protected Mode which uses AppContainers (rather than Integrity Levels) for isolation. EPM does not offer an API for interacting with cookies; IESetProtectedModeCookie will not set the cookie inside an AppContainer. [(source)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/20/wininet-ie-cookie-internals-faq.aspx?PageIndex=3)

But again, prefer to let the user relog himself.

Comment: Thanks @cyrbil I do use InternetSetCookie , which works for other pages within the same domain, however ever, when it is this one particular page on the same domain, cookies aren't passed. Programmatically when i make the call to the same page (same domain) i get cookies in my response, but when IE makes a call to the same page it doesnt pass the cookies which i have set using InternetSetCookie and hence prompting for logon. Strange, i am out of ideas ...

Comment: The domain is on Internet Zone, cookies are allows and is not in Protected mode, this method of mine works for other pages in the same URL, but a call to that one page also part of the same URL doesnt seem to pass the cookies

Comment: What i have noticed is that when i use InternetSetCookie or InternetSetCookieEx or IESetProtectedModeCookie , i do not see a txt file created for cookie in the directory 'Temporary Internet Files'

Comment: I have no environment configured to test it out right now. Could you give me information on you system (OS, IE, VS, ...)

Comment: And also provide your InternetSetCookieEx call.

Comment: I have modified the post with more details, i do not see much difference from InternetSetCookieEx  & InternetSetCookie , only thing is i can state if its a third party cookie or not.

Comment: InternetSetCookieEx  have flags as 4th parameter, specially: `INTERNET_COOKIE_THIRD_PARTY - Indicates that the cookie being set is a third-party cookie.` Please refer to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385108(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: but they both belong to the same URL  or domain, technically its not a third party cookie, i used to use InternetSetCookie, do i still need to specify that parameter?  I am not sure how to actually specify it. Can you help me with the syntax?

Comment: `InternetSetCookieEx(URL1, cookie1.Name, cookie1.Value, INTERNET_COOKIE_THIRD_PARTY);`

Comment: Could you try with `IESetProtectedModeCookie` instead ? I still don't have a windows in my hand to try more deeply.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80427/discussion-between-cyrbil-and-telson-alva).